# How technically rails process the request when we enter url in browser and press enter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, request, response

I am new in `rails`. I don't understand how `rails` process the `request` and `response`.

When I enter the `url` into browser for `rails app` and press enter. Then can any one walk me through what heppens in detail.

Comment: Without any reason why `down vote`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you types in a URL, hoping for a your page.

1. After the DNS gets resolved, the request hits a web server, which asks Rails what it has for that `url`.
2. Rails goes to the `routes.rb` file first, which takes the `URL` and calls a corresponding `controller` action.
3. The controller goes and gets whatever stuff it needs from the database using the relevant `model`.
4. With the data the `controller` got from the `model`, it uses the respective `view` to make some HTML.
5. `Rails` packs up the response and gives it to the web server.
   The web server delivers the response to the browser to display your page in the browser.

A good read:

[Examining Internals Of Rails Request Response Cycle](http://www.rubypigeon.com/posts/examining-internals-of-rails-request-response-cycle/)

Comment: Once DNS is resolved how does request goes to routes.rb ? How middle ware dispatch request to rails app ?

Comment: To this good answer, I would only add the following: rails has a lot of magic due to the philosophy "convention over configuration", meaning that a lot of the finding of the correct model/controller/action/view might happen without having it to specify it explicitly. E.g. if a view with the same name as the controller action existing within a folder with the same name as the controller, this will be automatically rendered at the end of the action

Answer (score 0):

In very simple terms,

`Action controller` takes control of request/response routes with the help of `routes.rb`
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html check this out for details about Action controller.

When you fire a rails request respective to your app,

1. Action controller processes the request and matches it with the routes in routes.rb. For example when you hit 
   `localhost:3000/about_us`
2. The routes are matched with `"/about_us" => "home#about_us"` it takes you to the home controller's about_us action, which in turn holds a view `(view/home/about_us.html.erb)` that would be displayed.